# node.js nodemailer and nodemailer-sendinblue-transport failing to send email

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have created an account with sendInBlue and imported nodemailer and nodemailer-sendinblue-transport into my project where I am trying to send a simply confirmation email. The following code is how I have attempted to setup:

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
  sendinblueTransport({
    auth: {
      apiKey: 'key'
    }
  })
);
```

The following code is a section of my signup method responsible for sending the confirmation email:

```js
return transporter.sendMail({
  to: email,
  from: 'person@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Signup succeeded!',
  html: '<h1>You successfully signed up!</h1>'
});
```

When I run my program the signup process succeeds but the following error is thrown instead of the email sending:

> Error: Key Not Found In Database (failure, 401)

I read that their v2 API might be depreciated but a member of their customer support says they still provide support for nodemailer, what could be the problem? I've also tried sendGrid and Mandrill but the former has a very buggy website that doesn't let me login and the latter requires an active domain to send emails.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you used the correct api key?

Comment: There's literally only two and I tried them both

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can resolve it using this way:

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'SendinBlue', // no need to set host or port etc.
    auth: {
        user: 'yourRegisteredEmailOnSendinblue@email.com',
        pass: 'smtp password here'
    }
});
```

Then you can call it as :

```
transporter.sendMail({
            to: 'recipientEmail@email.com',
            from: 'senderEmail@email.com',
            subject: 'Signup verification',
            html: '<h1>Please verify your email</h1><a href="www.google.com"> 
                   <button>Verify</button>'
        })
                .then((res) => console.`enter code here`log("Successfully sent"))
                .catch((err) => console.log("Failed ", err))
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const sibTransport = require('nodemailer-sendinblue-transport');

transport = nodemailer.createTransport(sibTransport({
    apiKey: '<my API v2 product key>',
  }));
```

Then send as described by @Shashank.

Comment: use `new sibTransport`

Answer (score 0):

Seems API url for v3 keys is "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/"
Default createTransport uses "https://api.sendinblue.com/v2/"

That`s why it is not worked from the start

Answer (score 0):

A solution to use Sendinblue with Nest `MailerModule` (typescript):

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { MailerModule } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer'
import { join } from 'path'
import { HandlebarsAdapter } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer/dist/adapters/handlebars.adapter'
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config'

@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        transport: {
          host: config.get('EMAIL_SMTP_ADDRESS'), // smtp-relay.sendinblue.com
          port: Number(config.get('EMAIL_SMTP_PORT')), // 587
          secure: false, // for dev purpose
          auth: {
            user: config.get('EMAIL_USER'), // the Login
            pass: config.get('EMAIL_PASSWORD') // any SMTP KEY VALUE (the SMTP KEY NAME is useless...)
          }
        },
        template: {
          dir: join(__dirname, 'templates'),
          adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
          options: {
            strict: true
          }
        }
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService]
    })
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using NodeMailer module only. Working as of 2023

If anyone here is not interested in using the module `nodemailer-sendinblue-transport module`. Here is the configuration. Tested and it worked.

```js
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp-relay.sendinblue.com',
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: 'YOUR_REGISTERED_EMAIL',
        pass: 'YOUR_MASTER_PASSWORD'
    }
})
```

This information can be found in this link when you are logged in
https://app.sendinblue.com/settings/keys/smtp

Answer (score 0):

For configuring with V3 API what worked for me in 2023:

1. You have to install `nodemailer-sendinblue-transport` package then use this simple configuration.
2. 

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const Transport = require("nodemailer-sendinblue-transport");
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
    new Transport({ apiKey: "my-api-key" })
);
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer-sendinblue-transport